# MvvmCross: Android Application attribute

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

When using MvvmCross for Android, where is the actual Application object normally used by Android?  This object is not always needed unless you want to customize the  tag in the manifest.  Mono for Android has a ApplicationAttribute that you can use to decorate the Application class and change themes, icons, etc.  How would I do this when using MvvmCross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvvmCross sits on top of Xamarin.Android

So you can customise an MvvmCross Android application in exactly the same way as you customise a normal Xamarin.Android applciation - create an Application override if you need one.

Note also that some application properties can be adjusted through project settings and assembly attributes http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml