# Define a base class for application class in Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an XYZ module, which is mainly a pre-built Xamarin Android java bindings library with some c# classes. In a "standalone" Xamarin Android project it works perfectly. But now I would like to implement as a plugin in my big cross-platform Xamarin project, which uses the MvvmCross framework, and follows the MvvmCross standard patterns.

The XYZ module requires to set a base class for the Android Application class, like this:

```
[Application]
public class Application : XYZApplication
{
  public Application(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
  { }
  public override void OnCreate()
  { base.OnCreate();}
}
```

Normally no application class is presented, the MvvmCross Setup.cs gets it from the core project, the CreateApp() method returns this class from the core:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
   public override void Initialize()
   {
     CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
     RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.StartupViewModel>();
    }
}
```

If I don't specify the Application class with the ApplicationAttribute, the XYZ module fails in its plugin. If I do, then the MvvmCross framework fails, when it want to load my plugins, the pluginloader fails with the very first plugin at this line:

```
manager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<PluginLoader>();
```

with the message "could not resolve type".

I think the source of the problem, that the Application class cannot have two base classes, or cannot be created twice?
Maybe there is a solution, if you need an application class defined, having a base class while using MvvmCross.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

The MvvmCross `App` is a PCL class which provides a place to initialize and list all your `ViewModel`s and other `Model` and `Service` code.

It's completely independent of any OS-specific `Application` or `AppDelegate` objects.

If you need a platform-specific `Application` then add one as a separate class.

We've tried to explain this a bit in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/High-Level-MvvmCross-Objects

See also [MvvmCross: Android Application attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642871/mvvmcross-android-application-attribute)

Comment: Thank you Stuart. I made a test (should have done before...), when I define my application class like this:  `public class MainApp : Application`  , based on the Android.App.Application then my project runs perfectly with MvvmCross.  But when I change the base class to XYZApplication, then MvvmCross fails with the first plugin's PluginLoader that could not resolve type. This XYZApplication comes from a java class which is in the bindings library, and it extends the Application class  `public class XYZApplication extends Application`. Maybe I'm missing or doing something wrong here.

Comment: Not sure anyone can help you at such an abstract XYZ level. Check trace, enable all the debug output you can, provide as much debug as you can - maybe in a new question - sounds like you have a specific issue just with XYZ - whatever it is.